# A (really!) cute identity between product of binomials

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, bijective-combinatorics

As an off-shot of my [earlier MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/415456/the-inverse-of-a-symbolic-matrix-with-reciprocal-binomials-has-laurent-entries), I have found a "really cute" identity. The connection is revealed in the limit $q\rightarrow 1$.

So, I would like to ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is there a combinatorial (conceptual) proof of this equality?
> $$\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{2i}i^2=2^n\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{n+i}i\binom{n}i \qquad \text{or} \qquad
> \prod_{i=1}^n\binom{2i}i^2=2^n\prod_{i=1}^n\binom{n+i}{i,i,n-i}.$$

Comment: Note that $\binom{n+i}i\binom ni=\binom{n+i}{n-i}\binom{2i}i$. The two identities can be easily seen.

Comment: This does not seem to address the question. Hope you agree.

Comment: Perhaps you could say something about the proof you have, and what you find "non-conceptual" or "non-combinatorial" about it. I was able to verify the formula by brute force, breaking things down into factorials and using the "cute" identity $(2^n)(n!)((2n-1)!!) = (2n)!!$, but I don't really know if that qualifies as the sort of proof you're looking for. Also, to amplify Zhi-Wei Sun's comment, the formula he points out immediately shows that your formula is equivalent to $\prod \binom{2i}{i} =2^n \prod \binom{n+i}{n-i}$ -- maybe simpler? Is there a reason you've stated it this way instead?

Comment: All that you (and Zhi-Wei) said makes sense, algebraically (and that is also how I could verify the identity). However, you can understand that such an approach would not be viewed as combinatorial (bijective proof, counting interpretations, etc). Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to remember examples of combinatorial proofs about _products_ of binomial coefficients rather than sums...

Comment: I suggest to remove the number theory tag, because you want a combinatorial proof.

Comment: @GHfromMO: removed.